# Getting zsh to honor dircolors-solarized

Tags: zsh, ls

So I'm faced up with this discrepancy between the way my ls displays colors via this:

https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized

Between that, and how zsh tab autocompletion display colors. I'll make this clear with an image:

[image]

Cheers in advance for any insights as to how to reconcile these two realms of listing directories!

Comment: What is the cool dark status bar you have in the bottom? Is it a desktop environment or window manager? Thanks!

Comment: @javidcf https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline It's tmux with this slapped on top of it, welcome to a new world of productivity, enjoy (If you're interested in the color scheme I got going on it shoot me a PM, cause I have no idea where I got that from in the first place)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`list-colors` is the style used by Zsh to set completion colors, it has its own funny syntax, use the following to set it to match your `LS_COLORS`:

```
# colored completion - use my LS_COLORS
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
```

BTW, this line comes straight from the zsh manual, `man zshall` and then search for `LS_COLORS`.